# PHP and Javascript image editing?

Tags: image, image-editing, image-editor

I'm looking for a site with a robust API or something I can house on my own server to do some image editing. Yes, I know about Pixlr and Photoshop.com, to name 2, but the API features I'm looking for go beyond that.

I am looking to take an image and add another image to it, with transparency. I also want to be able to add text to the image. The additional image need

Any suggestions will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have option to use OpenCV and implement functionalities that you need.

Comment: @svlada I have no restrictions. Can you cite an example using OpenCV?

Comment: There are already questions on this topic check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002895/is-there-anyway-to-integrate-opencv-with-php

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

Try this javascript library it works very nice :)